# How to remove HTML script tag with open type

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem where our byzantine PHP system is generating HTML for a user that includes the following tag in the header:

```
<span class="msg-text"><SCRIPT type="...</span><etc><etc>
```

Basically, everything after that dud script tag is broken and doesn't load (the content is completely blank).

I understand it's a hack solution, but I'm looking for a way to just remove that piece of HTML using jQuery. I've scoured a bunch of solutions but have so far only been able to target valid DOM objects. Because this tag doesn't exactly have a legitimate attribute I can hook into, I'm wondering if it's possible to simply target the HTML string and do something like

```
Replace('<SCRIPT type="...', '')
```

Would appreciate any help - I'm really not great with JavaScript.

Comment: The script will mostly likely already have executed (or thrown an error) before jQuery tries to remove it. Are you sure this will solve your issue?

Comment: I don't know for sure that it will be solved, but seems worth trying. Of course, fixing the source is a better option, but I don't have much faith in that being a quick outcome for a number of reasons.

Comment: The browser parses the HTML before anything runs. If there's invalid HTML, it will try to fix it up somehow.

Comment: get all HTML code  by .html() methode And replace like this `Replace('<SCRIPT type="...', '')` and reinject the new value to the DOM

Comment: Thanks folks. It doesn't sound like there's much I can do with jQuery. Looks like fixing at the source is the way to (try and!) go.